# Regex to insert and replace characters in a string C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string which looks like this :-
"$.ConfigSettings.DatabaseSettings.DatabaseConnections.SqlConnectionString.0.Id"
and I want the result to look like this :-
"$.ConfigSettings.DatabaseSettings.DatabaseConnections.SqlConnectionString[0].Id"

Basically wherever there is a single digit preceded and succeeded by a period I need to change it to [digit] followed by period ie [digit]. .I have seen tons of examples where people are only replacing the regex string.
How will I do this using Regex.Replace in C#

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input, @"\.(\d)(?=\.)", "[$1]")`

Comment: can u explain what this is ? and thanks a lot it worked.

Comment: See my answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"\.(\d)(?=\.)", "[$1]")

\.            - capture a "."
  (\d)        - then a single digit in a capturing group ($1 in the replacement)
      (?=     - start a positive lookahead
         \.   - that matches a "."
           )  - end the lookahead
```

So, it means : *(match a dot followed by a digit in a capturing group) only if it is followed by a dot*

So we matched `".0"` and captured `"0"`. We replace the entire match with `"[$1]"`, where `$1` refers to the first captured group.

See ["Grouping Constructs in Regular Expressions"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx for information about the different grouping constructs that I use in this solution.